# Azure Text detect which is handwriting or ocr

Tags: azure, text, ocr, handwriting

In azure they have 2 option to detect text from image which is handwriting or OCR, but I don't get the confidence score, so I need to get the best one text result,

And what engine can handle which is the best/similar based on spelling OR confidence score?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I too tried Azure API and sometimes it is not giving results as expected.What  score value are you getting.Also,I would suggest ,please compare this with [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)

Comment: well, for OCR maybe google is better, but for handwriting, azure is the best, the problem is how to detect which is image that contain OCR or Handwriting

Comment: haven't got anything specific to distinguish OCR and handwriting in Auzre yet. Can  be a addition to [https://feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/)